# A picture from windows 10 lock screen. I would like to know where it is!

Tags: air-travel

I have been scouring the internet to find where this place is! I havent had much luck.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The image is [Lightning over Kowloon, Hong Kong](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/daily-picture/9wzdncrfk0wk#) (copyright Daniel Chui/Moment/Getty Images). A Google image search pulls it right up.